# WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am using all latest versions as in below but still see the issue said in above. Can someone help with it.

- Eclipse IDE Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0);
- WebDriver (Java) - 3.141.59
- ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36

Here is my code:

```
package AutomationFrameWork;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;

public class FirstTestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\xxxx.000\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
         driver.get("www.google.ca");

         System.out.println("Successfully opened the website");


         driver.quit();


    }

}
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type
>       ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type
>       at AutomationFrameWork.FirstTestCase.main(FirstTestCase.java:15)

Comment: you have to call `System.setProperty` step,  prior to the ` WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

Comment: Put `System.setProperty` before initialize `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

Answer (score 0):

`System.setProperty()` should be prior to driver intialization.
Also check version of chrome browser and chrome driver are in sync.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give like this .Also better to put in a folder than putting on the desktop.

```
WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Jar_files\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```